# How can I do conditional build in React?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have made a website for my company which have theme system like wordpress. Now I've 4 themes. The selected theme name is coming with API. But it's taking all 4 themes when it get build.

Is there any way I can build the website with only the theme name coming from API? and remove other 3 themes code?

The site loading is effecting for loading all 4 themes. So It would be great to me if I could control build without unnecessary themes.

Here is my .env file, I'm taking the theme name from this. And conditionally code is after this.

```
REACT_APP_HOVERCRAFT_END_POINT='www.example.com' 
REACT_APP_SITE_URL='www.example.com' 
REACT_APP_FABLE_END_POINT='www.example.com' 
REACT_APP_REFRESH_POPUP_TIMEOUT=10 
REACT_APP_ASSETS_URL='/assets/'
REACT_APP_BRAND='brand' 
REACT_APP_TEMPLATE='delta' // Theme Name
REACT_APP_TEMPLATE_VAR='wun' 
REACT_APP_FOOTER_LOGO="alternate"
```

Conditional code: 
// Conditional Theme code

```
const flightFields = () => {
    switch (template) {
        case 'alfa':
            return require(./bravo); 
        case 'charlie':
            return require(./charlie); 
        case 'delta':
            return require(./delta);
        default:
            return require(./bravo); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your webpack file? Or at least a minimal example of how your are using the themes?

Comment: I have done nothing with webpack file. That's the default one.

Here is my .env file, I'm taking the theme name from this. And conditionally code is after this.

REACT_APP_HOVERCRAFT_END_POINT=''
REACT_APP_SITE_URL=''
REACT_APP_FABLE_END_POINT=''
REACT_APP_REFRESH_POPUP_TIMEOUT=10
REACT_APP_ASSETS_URL='/assets/'
REACT_APP_BRAND='brand'
REACT_APP_TEMPLATE='delta' // Theme Name
REACT_APP_TEMPLATE_VAR='wun'
REACT_APP_FOOTER_LOGO="alternate"